# Evaluate this integral $ s(t) = \int{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2G(M+m)(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{d})}} }$

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

I'm trying to get a displacement-time function from this velocity equation where $x$ represents time.

$ v(x) = \sqrt{2G(M+m)(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{d})} $

Since $v = \frac{dx}{dt}$, we can determine $s(t)$

$ s(x) = \int{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2G(M+m)(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{d})}} }$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Constants don't matter. Try a 
[substitution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0k7O.png) (spoiler alert).
Btw, isn't your left side is just $t$.

Comment: Oops, I forgot, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment,
but it's a start.

The constants don't matter,
so you need to do
$s(t) 
= \int{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{d})}} }
= \int{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{d-x}{xd}}} }
= \int{dx\sqrt{\frac{xd}{d-x}} }
= \sqrt{d}\int{dx\sqrt{\frac{x}{d-x}} }
$.

The rest is up to you.